# I am unable to read while loop in shell script

Tags: command-line

So i wrote this program to reverse the arguments..but the problem was while and expr command was not read by shell script.. Here is the program

```
#!/bin/sh

If test $# -eq 0

 then echo "not enough arguments "

else 
  echo " no. Of arguments is $#"

echo "the arguments are $*"

echo "the reverse of it is"

c=$#

while [ $c -ne 0 ]

do 

  eval echo \$$c

  c='expr $c - 1"

done
fi
```

I knew it was not reading while loop since the colour of while loop didn't change.

Comment: There are some basic syntax errors: `If` should be `if` (lowercase) and `c='expr $c - 1"` is wrong because you open the string with single quote but close it with double quote. Since you have a variable substitution, it should be: `c="expr $c - 1"`

Answer (score 0):

You can run the script with `bash -x` to see exactly what it's doing. I noticed it was comparing "expr 2 - 1" to see if it was equal to 0, which looked wrong. I think this line is wrong:

```
c='expr $c - 1"
```

The quotes don't match, so I originally suggested using double quotes, but what you want is to assign the *result* of running expr blah blah to the `c` variable, so you need backticks:

```
c=`expr $c - 1`
```

If you fix this, and the uppercase `If` near the beginning, the script seems to run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a `for` loop with bash's arithmetic expressions and [indirect variable expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
$ set -- a b c d e f
$ for (( c=$#; c>0; c--)); do echo ${!c}; done
f
e
d
c
b
a
```